# Livecode youtube live streaming with browser widget in livecode

Tags: livecode

Is it possible to alter the chromium browser to add support for h264 codecs that youtube is using for live streams, for example
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KF47Za1lfjM

These are unsupported in the browser widget as the chromium instance does not support the streaming. Is it a difficult thing to update the chromium instance with another version which supports the streams?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you post this as a bug or feature request in http://quality.livecode.com/.  You are more likely to get an answer there from someone who does the builds.